# insertar registros de un archivo excel a una DB MS access delphi

Tags: excel, ms-access, delphi

Estoy haciendo un programa que haga importaciones Excel a la base de datos, 
este es mi código:

```
var
importdir, ipo: string;
begin
if OpenDialog1.Execute then
begin
importdir := ExtractFileDir( OpenDialog1.FileName );
ipo := OpenDialog1.FileName;
end;
ADOConnection1.Execute( 'insert into archivo select * from [Excel 8.0;  database='+ipo+'].hoja1' );
end;
```

cuando selecciono el archivo me aparece este error

> el jet de Microsoft no pudo encontrar el objeto 'hoja1' Asegúrese de que el objeto exista y la ruta sea correcta.

Comment: En queries a Excel, los nombres de hoja van seguidos de un símbolo de dólar, por lo que probablemente te funcione con solo cambiar `hoja1` por `hoja1$`

Comment: hola jachguate con el signo dolar funciono pero tengo un pequeño problema,cuando hago la inserción por primera vez la grilla no me muestra los registros cargados pero cuando ejecuto el programa por segunda vez muestra los registro que cargue previamente

Comment: problema resuelto. gracias a por sus aportes

Comment: Me alegra @pablo, lo publiqué como respuesta para que alguien más que llegue acá por la búsqueda pueda ver claramente cual fue la solución. Un saludo.

Answer (score 0):

Dada que las conexiones con ADO deben ser diferentes para conectar a Excel y a MSAccess (dodo que no lo dices asumo que lo estás haciendo con ADO), creo que la solución pasa por insertar los registros uno a uno.
Crea 2 conexiones una para Excel y otra para Access.

> Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Password="";Data Source=.\DatosExcel.xls;Extended Properties="Excel 8.0;HDR=Yes;IMEX=1";Persist Security Info=True

.

> Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Password="";Data Source=.DatosAccess.mdb;Persist Security Info=True

A partir de ahí se trata de ir leyendo registros utilizando un ADOQuery/ADOTable desde una conexión e insertándolos utilizando la otra.

Comment: hola German, ya pude solucionar el problema con la conexion

Answer (score 0):

Por regla general, cuando haces queries utilizando el *JetEngine* contra Excel, los nombres de hoja van seguidos de un símbolo de dólar, por lo que probablemente te funcione con solo cambiar hoja1 por hoja1$, algo así:

```
begin
  if OpenDialog1.Execute then
    ADOConnection1.Execute( 'insert into archivo select * from [Excel 8.0;  database=' + OpenDialog1.FileName + '].hoja1$');
end;
```

Un saludo.

Comment: si, con este método me sirvió ya que tenia el if fuera del begin, cuando cancelaba la importacion del Excel me generaba un bug pero ahora ya no

Comment: enhorabuena @pablo. En StackOverflow, puedes marcar una respuesta como aceptada. Esto ayudará a futuros visitantes de este hilo a identificar la respuesta que para tu caso fue la correcta. Puedes aprovechar esa característica también cuando estás investigando, pues identificas rápidamente, de entre todas las respuestas, cuál fue la que le sirvió al OP.